# How does global variables in JavaScript work?

Tags: javascript, global-variables, scope

I m a newbie to javascript. I usually program in Java. I am confused by this following code snippet.

```
<script>
 x = "foo";

function bar(p){
  if (p){
    document.writeln("x = " + x);
  } else {
    var x = "baz";
  }
}

bar("baz");

</script>
```

When I run the above code snipped its printing

```
 x = undefined
```

Why does it print undefined, since x is a global variable it should print foo right ? Can anyone explain ?

Comment: don't add var to x in in `var x = "baz";` just `x = "baz";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> since x is a global variable it should print foo right

It would if it wasn't shadowed by the `var x = "baz";` declaration further up in your function; due to hoisting it will execute the function as if you wrote

```
function bar(p){
  var x; // = undefined

  if (p){
    document.writeln("x = " + x);
  } else {
    x = "baz";
  }
}
```

To make the code do what you want, you could simply write `x = "baz";` instead of `var x = "baz";`.

Answer (score 0):

try this output is `x = foo`

```
var x="foo";
function bar(p){

  if (p){
    document.writeln("x = " + x);
  } else {
    x = "baz";
  }
}

bar("baz");
```